# Retrieved HTML inaccessible by "outer" javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I have a big problem. I am retrieving content using ajax in form of html. the problem is that my main js cannot do any operations on any retrieved tags, classes, ids, nothing. Is it meant to be like this? How do I perform operations on retrieved data?

Example:

someserverfile.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET['myquery'] == "something")
{
    echo "<input type='text' id='input_test' value='SomeValue'>";
}
?>
```

main.js

```
$(function(){
    $("#somebutton").on("click", function() {
       $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "someserverfile.php?myquery=something",
          success: function(response) {
             $("#somecontentdiv").html(response);
          }
       });
    });

    //now i have retrieved the input, but when i try to change its value, nothing happens. Why?

    $("#input_test").val("NewValue");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it inside of the success function:

Place $("#input_test").val("NewValue"); inside of success function after you change the content of the #somecontentdiv.

```
$(function(){
    $("#somebutton").on("click", function() {
       $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "someserverfile.php?myquery=something",
          success: function(response) {
             $("#somecontentdiv").html(response);

            $("#input_test").val("NewValue");
          }
       });
    });

    //now i have retrieved the input, but when i try to change its value, nothing happens. Why?

    //moved to success function $("#input_test").val("NewValue");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah.. its because the request is asynchronous. Gotta do changes to the retrieved html inside the success function. problem solved :)

Comment: This should be a comment to @LarryLane's answer.  Please be sure to mark his answer up, and mark it solved, to give him credit for helping you.